# Toricelli's law of efflux in moving container

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

[image]Suppose there is a big tank of water with a small hole near the bottom. Now if this tank starts moving with say a velocity 'v', then will Toricelli's law hold? I tried directly applying Bernoulli's equation taking into account the velocity of the container, which gives me a result of absolute velocity of efflux as square root of $(u^2 + 2gh)$. But can we use the Bernoulli's law here?

Also another question - Now what will be the force exerted by the ejected fluid on the tank?

Comment: i want to know more about your question (*it looks cool*) can you give more information, please and yes i think bernoulli's law can be applied!

Comment: I meant that there is a water tank that is moving with a velocity towards say right. There is a hole near the bottom on the left side. Now when the water comes out, what will be its velocity with respect to the ground to wrt the tank? Can we use Bernoulli's eqn? Then will we include this velocity 'v' in it?

Comment: Show us how you came up with that result.  A tank moving horizontally at a constant velocity v is an inertial frame of reference, and the laws of physics do not change between inertial frames of reference.

Comment: yes! if air resistance is neglected then you will see the water coming out will also move with velocity $v$ in horiz. direction and it will be stationary in horiz. direction w.r.t container! so happily apply bernoulli's law

Comment: So is what I did correct? Also how would the ejected fluid exert force now?

Comment: @Shodai: Chester Miller is 100 % correct. Carry out this experiment on a train moving at constant speed and the result is the same as carrying it out on the passenger platform (stationary). Things would be different if there was *acceleration* by the train going on but that is a different question from yours.

Comment: Google gallilean reference frame. I assume you are only considering steady state,  constant velocity. As an observer in that frame, with your bucket you would observe nothing different than if the frame was at zero velocity.

Comment: As reckoned from a stationary frame of reference relative to the moving tank, the fluid flow is non-steady-state.  So to apply the Bernoulli equation to this situation, a non-steady-state version of the Bernoulli equation must be used.  I haven't figured out how to do this yet.  From a frame of reference of an observer moving with the tank, the usual steady state version can be used, and the Toricelli law is obtained.

Comment: @Gert:So by same result is it that if I am in the train then will be velocity of efflux as seen by me will be root of 2gh, or do you mean that I should apply Bernoulli's equation to get the result that I got? 
I got it that it's an intertial frame, so I can apply Bernoulli's law in the frame of the Moving tank also, but then why am I getting different results?

Comment: @Shodai As I said in my previous answer, you can't use the standard bernoulli equation to get the correct result for the moving train (if you do the analysis from a fixed from of reference).  You need to use a modified version of the Bernoulli equation that takes into account the non-steady nature of the flow as reckoned from the stationary frame.  If you use the modified version, you will get the same answer.  Google "Transient Bernoulli Equation."

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So then the result is that whether I'm in a train or on ground, the velocity with which I will see water coming out will be same? That is, relative velocity of efflux will always remain same?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.